# Assigning a unique id to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui to create draggable divs that are contained within a div of class name `middle-side`. The event occurs during an button click trigger. Text is also appended to the newly created div. The text is placed in a `<span>` tag inside the draggable div.  The problem is how can I assign a unique div id to the newly created draggable divs somethind like `<div id="drag1"`, `<div id="drag2">`, `<div id="drag3"`, etc.? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/46/)

I know they are frameworks like knockout, angular, etc but wanted to stick with what I know.

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(".draggable").remove();
});

var z = 1;
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        html: '<span class="close">[X]</span><span class="text">' + $('textarea').val() + '</span>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    }).addClass('placement');


    /** Contain draggable div **/
    $('.middle-side').parent().mousemove(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
        $('.placement').css({'top': relY + 30,'left': relX + 10, 'position': 'absolute'});
    })

});

/** Place a temporary dashed border on div after initial creation**/
$('.middle-side').on('click', function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
    $('.placement').css({'top': relY,'left': relX, 'position': 'absolute' });
    $(this).off("mousemove").find('.placement').removeClass('placement')    
}); 

$('body').on('click', '.draggable .close', function () {
    $(this).closest('.draggable').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another property to your *div* element:

```
var z = 1,
    id = 1;
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        id : "drag" + id++,
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        html: '<span class="close">[X]</span><span class="text">' + $('textarea').val() + '</span>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    }).addClass('placement');
```

I've also updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/48/

Comment: Could i be able to also do add that id to the span tag inside the draggable div like `<span class="text_1">`?

Comment: For the span in the inserted html you can directly add an id: http://jsfiddle.net/5ux25pcn/

Comment: Are you sure you added the correct fiddle? I dont see any changes

Comment: There's one change: I've added the id for the span, here: <span id="foo" class="close"> If you need it at the other span, just add it there...

Answer (score 0):

Just create an id and directly assign it. Whenever you call uniqueId(), you will always get a unique one since the counter is global.

```
var counter = 0;
var triggerclick = false;
uniqueId = function(){
    return 'drag' + counter++
}
```

Example...

```
$( myDiv ).attr( "id", uniqueId());
```